# Keep getting error "E: Unable to locate package [package name]"

Tags: 18.04, unsupported-packages

I have recently purchased a Raspberry Pi 4, and am currently running Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS on it installed by the Raspberry Pi Imager.

I am trying to install a dev tool, either Sublime-text or Atom but when running the install command I get the error "Unable to locate package". Now these packages aren't available for Bionic when I check on https://packages.ubuntu.com/

What do I do to fix this problem? I would really like to use one of these dev tools as I have to do some c++ programming on the RPi. Or is the package just not supported even though some tutorials explicitly state how to install sublime or atom for Ubuntu 18.04.

EDIT: As of this post, the packages aren't supported (yet). So I'll try to find a different dev tool to continue my journey.

Comment: It doesn't install Sublime or Atom at all. It is unable to locate the packages for me. Even after running the commands stated in the code part of that topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you uses Raspberry Pi, the architecture you had is [`arm`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture)— unfortunately those two program you mentioned does not support ARM Builds.

- https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/57456/installing-atom-text-editor-on-rasberry-pi
- https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/54711/installing-sublime-text-on-raspberry-pi

So to answer the main question, **yes the packages does not support your machine at the moment**. Hopefully in the future it will.